# How to get malware campaign runners to use my mail honeypot?

Tags: malware, honeypot

I have a working mail honeypot but have yet to receive any malware. I've already tried submitting my domain to several unsubscribe forms, but it does not seem to have worked. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14745/how-to-attract-traffic-to-a-honeypot

Comment: sign up for porn and usenet newsletters and sit back and wait for the malarkey to roll in.

Comment: @schroeder I disagree that this is a duplicate; that question is asking about traffic, whereas I'm specifically looking to get malware

Comment: @dandavis would that not be considered tainting the data, as you are providing an email address and such websites will send non-spam emails to you?

Comment: traffic translates into getting malware ... attention = traffic = malware