# How to set up a Virtual Machine for a Honeypot?

Tags: honeypot

On this [thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10168/setting-up-a-honeypot), it's stated that it's probably a good idea to use a VM for your honeypot. I believe this is because;

- Comparative data is easier when comparing 2 exact images.
- Host/Network Security is probably easier
- Quicker to clean up/set up additional pots.

Looking for a step by step process so any NEW researchers can get it the OS up and running by your answer. This will also be Part 1 of "How to setup a honeypot" series of questions.

How would you set up a VM for a honey pot?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit this question to be less [su] material, along the lines of `"which characteristics are important in a VM that will be used as a honeypot"`, or `"what differences to make in a VM for HP"`. That said, I'm sure it would also depend on your honeypot definition, and what you're planning to do with it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When considering advice, such as it is better to use a VM to host a honeypot, I think it important to also consider what conditions may have changed since that advice became 'popular'. In this case for example, it would be important to be familiar with new threats, such as 'Crisis' see http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/08/crisis-espionage-malware-targets-virtual-machines/ , as this malware has the potential to undermine your analysis because it can even infect a non-running VM image, thereby compromising your 'known' good/clean base.

Tim